# Can a ball be a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

For a metric space $(M, d)$ and a set $E \subset M$, $(E, d_E)$ is also a metric space (where $d_E$ is just $d$ restricted to $E$

Consider the standard euclidean space on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is a ball $B_1(0)$ along with the euclidean metric be a "metric space"?

If not, then are there other restrictions for metric spaces that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, by the very statement that begins your question.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel thanks, you may post this as an answer and I'll accept it. It may seem trivial but I needed to verify my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the theorem you quoted at the start of your question, $B_1(0)$ with the Euclidean metric is a metric space.